# SSAS Cube: Many to Many Relationship Issue

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube, msbi

I created a many to many relationship between Dim_Vendor & Dim_Product using Dim_VendorProduct as Many to Many Connector Measure. Now i want to connect the Profit Percentage(from Dim_VendorProduct) & CustomerAmount(from FactCustomer) & multiply them in calculated Member. Is there a way to connect the Dim_VendorProduct table & Dim_Product table values, I am only getting nulls as result for calculated member

[Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ4Ly.png)

[Dimension Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q69mp.png)

Comment: In the last statement you ask to connect table values between dim_vendorproduct and dim_product, according to your schema, they appear to be joined already, you should have access to the values of that table.

Comment: I am able to access the ProfitPercentage value but when in calculated field i try to multiply ProfitPercentage & CustomerAmount. I only get null values. Even when i just do ProfitPercentage*10 in calculated member, I still get only nulls.

Comment: Sorry I was just reviewing questions and I don't have intimate knowledge of cubes